# Compute the exact minimum distance of a QECC with integer linear programming method

Tags: error-correction

Recently I'm reading the [paper of Bivariate Bicycle(BB) QLDPC code proposed by IBM](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07915). The paper mentioned that:

> The actual distance of each candidate code was computed using the integer linear programming method

and it refered to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5738.pdf) for the mixed ILP method for computing the exact code distance. This referenced paper primarily discusses ILP for MLE decoding in color codes. I am struggling to understand how the ILP method for MLE decoding can be adapted to compute code distances. Is  there any connection between these two problems?

Comment: For classical codes this paper has details : https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=XJtGE-oAAAAJ&citation_for_view=XJtGE-oAAAAJ:9yKSN-GCB0IC  I tried it on small codes with matlab and seems to work ok but I don't think it scales very well.

Comment: A very concrete example is [this pull request being written for stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/pull/703), which will convert a circuit into a WDIMACS description of the shortest error as a maxsat problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is python code that generates the stabilizers and observables of the IBM code, then produces a stim circuit measuring the Z stabilizers and observables after applying noise, then turns the distance-finding problem into a maxSAT problem solved by `pysat`:

```python
import time

import stim


def make_code() -> tuple[list[stim.PauliString], list[stim.PauliString], list[stim.PauliString]]:
    offsets = {1, -1, 1j, -1j, 3 + 6j, -6 + 3j}
    w = 24
    h = 12

    def wrap(c: complex) -> complex:
        return c.real % w + (c.imag % h)*1j

    def index_of(c: complex) -> int:
        c = wrap(c)
        return int(c.real + c.imag * w) // 2

    stabilizers: list[stim.PauliString] = []
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            if x % 2 != y % 2:
                continue  # This is a data qubit.
            m = x + 1j*y
            basis = 'XZ'[x % 2]
            sign = -1 if basis == 'Z' else +1
            stabilizer = stim.PauliString(w * h // 2)
            for offset in offsets:
                stabilizer[index_of(m + offset * sign)] = basis
            stabilizers.append(stabilizer)

    completed_tableau = stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers(
        stabilizers,
        allow_redundant=True,
        allow_underconstrained=True,
    )
    obs_indices = [
        k
        for k in range(len(completed_tableau))
        if completed_tableau.z_output(k) not in stabilizers
    ]
    observable_xs: list[stim.PauliString] = [
        completed_tableau.x_output(k)
        for k in obs_indices
    ]
    observable_zs: list[stim.PauliString] = [
        completed_tableau.z_output(k)
        for k in obs_indices
    ]

    return stabilizers, observable_xs, observable_zs


def make_z_basis_circuit(stabilizers: list[stim.PauliString], obs_zs: list[stim.PauliString]):
    num_qubits = len(stabilizers[0])
    circuit = stim.Circuit()
    circuit.append("X_ERROR", range(num_qubits), 1e-3)
    for k, observable in enumerate(obs_zs):
        circuit.append("MPP", stim.target_combined_paulis(observable))
        circuit.append("OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE", stim.target_rec(-1), k)
    for stabilizer in stabilizers:
        if stabilizer.pauli_indices('Z'):
            circuit.append("MPP", stim.target_combined_paulis(stabilizer))
            circuit.append("DETECTOR", stim.target_rec(-1))
    return circuit


def main():
    t0 = time.monotonic()

    stabilizers, obs_xs, obs_zs = make_code()
    circuit = make_z_basis_circuit(stabilizers, obs_zs)
    wcnf_string = circuit.shortest_error_sat_problem(format='WDIMACS')
    t1 = time.monotonic()
    print(f"Problem created in {t1 - t0:0.3f}s")

    from pysat.examples.rc2 import RC2
    from pysat.formula import WCNF
    wcnf = WCNF(from_string=wcnf_string)
    with RC2(wcnf) as rc2:
        rc2.compute()
        print(f"distance = {rc2.cost}")
    t2 = time.monotonic()
    print(f"Problem solved in {t2 - t1:0.3f}s")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code will run for a minute or two then print:

```
Problem created in 0.012s
distance = 12
Problem solved in 112.547s
```

Answer (score 2):

The author of the paper provided the implementation in [the repository](https://github.com/sbravyi/BivariateBicycleCodes/blob/main/distance_test.py).